# My SFDX Project in VS Code doesn't pickup any test classes

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, code-coverage, vs-code

Even though I have test classes and test methods in my SFDX project in VS Code none of the test methods gets picked up in the test panel.

[image]

I have configured a JDK in my VSCode here
[image]

and enabled
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, I can't answer your question, but I want to thank you for pointing out that VS Code has this feature, I hadn't seen it before. I haven't done anything special with settings (apart from making a connection with a sandbox), but somehow VS Code just shows all my Apex test classes and methods, and I can run them.

Comment: Which structure are you using for the project, metadata (the old one) or source tracking (the one that came with SFDX) one?

Comment: @alba-rivas I'm using the SFDX project structure.

Comment: Where do Apex test classes live? Directly in the classes folder? Or do you have subfolders? Can you share a screenshot maybe? And also of one of your test classes

Comment: I think I figured it out. In my test classes I have used the annotation isTest, When I changed it to IsTest (note the capitalization), the plug-in started to identify my test classes. May be there is no "equalsIgnoreCase" in the plug-in code :-)

Comment: Similar question with alternative solutions:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/414085/108203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. In my test classes I have used the annotation **isTest**, When I changed it to **IsTest** (note the capitalization), the plug-in started to identify my test methods.

May be there is no "equalsIgnoreCase" in the plug-in code :-)